# Bitwise OR operator confusion

Tags: c

Can anyone tell me the difference between the following two assignments?

```
control_reg |= (1<<2) | (1<<4);


control_reg = (1<<2) | (1<<4);
```

Comment: Look up the difference between |= and =. Your course should have covered that. For homework you should use the homework tag and not expect full answers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a pure programming question, not specifically related to microcontroller programming. It should be asked at https://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> control_reg |= (1<<2) | (1<<4);

This only affects bits 2 and 4 -- all of the other bits in `control_reg` are left unmodified.

> control_reg = (1<<2) | (1<<4);

This modifies all the bits in `control_reg` -- bits 2 and 4 are set to 1 and all the other bits are set to 0.